# Download SharePoint folder using Python

Tags: python-3.x, sharepoint, python-requests

I am using requests library in python to get pages from SharePoint 2010 and it's working fine, now I need to walk through a SharePoint directory and download all files from there to my local machine. Ideally, I would map it as a drive on my computer but this option is not on the table. How would I achieve this using python?

```
def __init__(self, url, domain, username, password):
    self.domain = domain
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
    self.url = url
    self.session = requests.Session()
    self.request = None
    self.authentication = HttpNtlmAuth(("%s\\%s" % (self.domain,
                                                    self.username)),
                                       self.password)
    self.headers = {'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'}
    self.request_page(self.url)

def request_page(self, url):
    relative_url = urljoin(self.url, url)
    print(relative_url)
    self.request = self.session.get(relative_url,
                                    auth=self.authentication,
                                    headers=self.headers)
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: @VaibhavMule, my request codes are working fine, I need directions on how to download files from SharePoint using Python.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?